# Incrementing an enum var to next element in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm implementing a Tic-Tac-Toe in Java, and have an enum declared like this:

```java
public enum Player{X,O};
```

When a movement is made, I need to swap to the other player, and I am doing it like:

```java
this.nextPlayer = ((this.nextPlayer == Player.X)?Player.O:Player.X);
```

Is there a way of automatically "increment" through the next element of an enum structure? I was wondering about having 5 or 6 different values, and wanting to swap through them without a huge code in it (and without implementing a separated method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ordinal() method of enums together with the modulus operator to achieve that:

```
this.nextPlayer = (nextPlayer.ordinal() + 1) % Player.values().length;
```

Comment: `values()` returns an array, so it should be `.length` instead of `.size()`

Comment: ordinal() FTW! Thanks a lot! :)